# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null at game.js:51

Tags: javascript, html

I tried with `window.onload = fuction () {};` without positive results ...
The error occurs when I go to PLAY (it's another html game.html) and that error comes out. The idea of the app is to choose a category and difficulty of the Quiz (it is an API) And I get the array, but at the moment of pressing PLAY it throws the error I mentioned.

App url in git: https://gitlab.com/silvatapialuis/quiz-app

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Open Trivia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" rel="icon" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="home" class="flex-center flex-column">
        <h1>Open Trivia</h1>
        <h5>Select Category:</h5>
        <button id="fetch">FETCH URL</button>
        <form name="formul1" class="cont">
          <select id="cat" name="cat" onchange="selectCat()">
            <option value="">Any Category</option>
            <option value="&category=9">General Knowledge</option>
            <option value="&category=10">Entertaiment: Books</option>
            <optiseon value="&category=11">Entertaiment: Film</option>
              <option value="&category=12">Entertaiment: Music</option>
              <option value="&category=13">Entertaiment: Musicals & Theatres</option>
              <option value="&category=14">Entertaiment: Television</option>
              <option value="&category=15">Entertaiment: Video Games</option>
              <option value="&category=16">Entertaiment: Board Games</option>
                                            .
                                            .
                                            .
          </select>
        </form>
        <h5>Select Difficulty:</h5>
        <form name="formul2" class="cont">
          <select id="diff" name="diff" onchange="selectDiff()">
            <option value="">Any Difficulty</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=easy">Easy</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="&difficulty=hard">Hard</option>
          </select>
        </form>
        <a class="btn" href="/game.html">Play</a>
        <a class="btn" href="/highscores.html">High Scores</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*game.js*

//CLICK EVENT BUTTON

```
var btnFetch = document.getElementById('fetch');

/*Line 51*/btnFetch.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('Would fetch newUrl:', newUrl);
  fetch(newUrl)
    .then(res => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(loadedQuestions => {
      console.log(loadedQuestions.results);
      questions = loadedQuestions.results.map(loadedQuestion => {
        const formattedQuestion = {
          question: loadedQuestion.question
        };

        const answerChoices = [...loadedQuestion.incorrect_answers];
        formattedQuestion.answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        answerChoices.splice(
        formattedQuestion.answer - 1,
        0,
        loadedQuestion.correct_answer
        );
        answerChoices.forEach((choice, index) => {
          formattedQuestion["choice" + (index + 1)] = choice;
        });

        return formattedQuestion;
      });

                               .
                               .
                               .
});
```

*game.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Quick Quiz - Play</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">      
      <div id="loader"></div>
      <div id="game" class="justify-center flex-column hidden">
        <div id="hud">
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p id="progressText" class="hud-prefix">
              Question
            </p>
            <div id="progressBar">
              <div id="progressBarFull"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="hud-item">
            <p class="hud-prefix">
              Score
            </p>
            <h1 class="hud-main-text" id="score">
              0
            </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h2 id="question"></h2>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">A</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">B</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="2"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">C</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="3"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="choice-container">
          <p class="choice-prefix">D</p>
          <p class="choice-text" data-number="4"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container1">
      <a class="btn" href="/">Go Home</a>
    </div>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow ! Could you edit your question add crop your code to the relevent part only ? Also, refer to the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section in order to ask a complete and answerable question

Comment: I think game.js I have made it clearer

Comment: What’s in game.html? If that’s the page the error happens on, it seems a lot more important than index.html.

Comment: The `<script>` tag should be either in the `<head>` or the `<body>` and not a sibling of `<html>`

Comment: Make the changes and follow the same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `document.getElementById('fetch')` is yielding *nothing* so my first guess is that the element is not on the page when the code is executed.

This could happen if the JS code is executed before the browser has had a chance to parse that element, but based on your code I would venture to guess that including the script outside of the `<html>` tag is your issue. Try placing it as the last child of the `<body>` tag, just before `</body>`.

Placing the `<script>` before the closing `<body>` ensures that all your HTML has been parsed by the browser before it runs your JS.

Comment: Which page are you experiencing the error? The element with an id of `fetch` isn't available on `game.html` but is on `index.html` according to your provided HTML. So I would expect an error on `game.html` because you're including `game.js` on that page and it expects to find that element.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your reference to game.js at the end of the body, rather than outside the html.

```
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @LuisFernandoSilva please can you copy the exact error you are getting?